# How to break eval(variable) if spaces in variable rise error?

Tags: python, eval

From what I know about `eval`, user can type anything and make it a command, so for example write a command to delete all folders on your computer. I am curious how to make eval safe. Are there any commands without spaces that are dangerous?

I made a code where user can input variable math_fun, I would like to make it safer:

```
def fun(a=1, b=1, c=1, math_fun='a*(x**2)+b*x+c'):
        if ' ' in math_fun:
            raise SpacesInsideVariable()
        x = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
        y = (lambda a,b,c,x: eval(math_fun))(a,b,c,x)
        print(x)
        print(y)
        return y

user_input = input()
fun(math_fun = user_input)
```

Comment: what do you mean by safe ? Can you bring in some context ?

Comment: From what I know about eval, user can type anything and make it a command, so for example write a command to delete all folders on your computer. I am curious how to make eval safe. Are there any commands without spaces that are dangerous?

Comment: @Gerard the question would be better if you edit and put that comment in the main question :) (and also specify where the input is coming from in this case)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean: does forbidding spaces prevent arbitrary code execution, then no. This works:

```py
eval("__import__('os').system('pwd')")
```

Since `os.system` gets you to the shell, there are techniques for working around forbidden spaces.

For more information see e.g.

- https://research.cs.wisc.edu/mist/SoftwareSecurityCourse/Chapters/3_8_3-Code-Injections.pdf
- https://www.betterhacker.com/2016/10/command-injection-without-spaces.html

I actually can't see a path to malicious code execution if you limit to only numbers and mathematical operators, but I'm willing to be proven wrong.